# Perl command to find pattern and extract fixed position fields

Tags: perl

I have file like this

```
FHEAD0000000001RTLG202106182103132021061430914  
THEAD0000000002100  202106141001180000000310  
TITEM  
THEAD  
TITEM  
FTAIL
```

I want to extract store and business date from FHEAD record
There will be ONLY one FHEAD record in the file

Store is from position 41 - 5digits ON FHEAD RECORD
Business date is from position 33 - 8 digits ON FHEAD RECORD

I tried below command

```
perl -lne ' ($s, $d) = (substr($_, 41, 5), substr($_, 33, 8)) if /FHEAD/; print "$ARGV,$s,$d"; ' $file
```

but it is looping through all records in file and printing multiple rows instead of one
I am getting output as
Whereas, there should be only one line

```
RTLOG_OMS_30914_20210618210313_71111119.dat.2,30914,20210614
RTLOG_OMS_30914_20210618210313_71111119.dat.2,30914,20210614
RTLOG_OMS_30914_20210618210313_71111119.dat.2,30914,20210614
RTLOG_OMS_30914_20210618210313_71111119.dat.2,30914,20210614
RTLOG_OMS_30914_20210618210313_71111119.dat.2,30914,20210614
RTLOG_OMS_30914_20210618210313_71111119.dat.2,30914,20210614
RTLOG_OMS_30914_20210618210313_71111119.dat.2,30914,20210614
RTLOG_OMS_30914_20210618210313_71111119.dat.2,30914,20210614
RTLOG_OMS_30914_20210618210313_71111119.dat.2,30914,20210614
RTLOG_OMS_30914_20210618210313_71111119.dat.2,30914,20210614
RTLOG_OMS_30914_20210618210313_71111119.dat.2,30914,20210614
RTLOG_OMS_30914_20210618210313_71111119.dat.2,30914,20210614
RTLOG_OMS_30914_20210618210313_71111119.dat.2,30914,20210614
RTLOG_OMS_30914_20210618210313_71111119.dat.2,30914,20210614
RTLOG_OMS_30914_20210618210313_71111119.dat.2,30914,20210614
RTLOG_OMS_30914_20210618210313_71111119.dat.2,30914,20210614
RTLOG_OMS_30914_20210618210313_71111119.dat.2,30914,20210614
RTLOG_OMS_30914_20210618210313_71111119.dat.2,30914,20210614
```

Comment: "_there should be only one line_" - ... are all those `RTLOG_...` lines actually on one line? Where does `RTLOG_OMS` and `.dat` etc come from? Those are not in the file you read.

Comment: Your print is unconditional.

Answer (score 4):

The `substr` and regex answers are fine, but there's an often overlooked tool called `unpack`.

The format specifiers are in the [pack](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack) documentation. The `A` is an ASCII character and the number following it is its length. So, `A5` is the next five ASCII characters. Each specifier produces one list item. `A28` skips over stuff to get to the right position, then `A8` gets the date and `A5` get store.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use v5.10;

while( <DATA> ) {
    next unless /\AFHEAD/;
    my( $header, $fill, $date, $store ) = unpack 'A5 A28 A8 A5', $_;

    say "DATE: $date";
    say "STORE: $store";
    last;
    }


__END__
FHEAD0000000001RTLG202106182103132021061430914
THEAD0000000002100 202106141001180000000310
TITEM
THEAD
```

This produces:

```
DATE: 20210614
STORE: 30914
```

Even if you don't want to use `pack`, note that I do another thing you can incorporate into the other answers. Skip lines until you get to the one you want, then process that line and terminate the loop. Once you have the line, you don't need to look at any other lines.

As a one liner, this might be something like this, using the `x` specifier to skip to an absolute position:

```
% perl -lne 'next unless /\AFHEAD/; print join "\t", unpack q(x33 A8 A5); last' file.txt
20210614    30914
```

This gets more interesting as you deal with more fields.

Answer (score 1):

Your print is unconditional. You only want to print if the line matches:

```
perl -lne ' print $ARGV,substr($_, 41, 5), substr($_, 33, 8) if /FHEAD/;' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see if following command produces desired output

```
 perl -lne 'print "date=$1 store=$2" if /FHEAD.{28}(.{8})(.{5})/' file
```

Output

```
date=20210614 store=30914
```

Comment: Thanks @polar-bear  This command is working fine for me.   How do I change the format of date to **DD-MON-YYYY**

Comment: perl -lne 'print "date=$3-$2-$1 store=$4" if /FHEAD.{28}(.{4})(.{2})(.{2})(.{5})/' file